# Does the pullback functor associated to an open surjection preserve quotient maps?

Tags: general-topology

Let $f \colon X \to Y$ be an open surjection, and $\alpha \colon A \to Y$, $\beta \colon B \to Y$.

If $q \colon A \to B$ is a quotient map, can we say that $X \times_Y q \colon X \times_Y A \to X \times_Y B$ is a quotient map?
Surjectivity is clear, but I'm not making progress on showing that $(X \times_Y q)^{-1}(U)$  being open implies $U$ is open.

**EDIT:** If it helps, we can maybe also assume additionally that $f$ be a local homeomorphism.